# Exporting multiple types

Tags: flowtype

I have lots of types defined throughout my file. I want to put a single line at the bottom of my file that does all the exports. So I can easily see what all is exported. Is this possible?

```
type foo = ...;

type bar = ...;


export types { foo, bar }
```

For instance this is how I export multiple in ES6:

```
function work(name) {
    ...
}
class Person {
    ...
}

export { work, Person }
export default Person
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the syntax is simply

```
export type {foo, bar}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh I was off by an `s`! Thanks sir. Is this mentioned in the docs, may you please link?

Comment: Normal `export type` is mentioned here: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/ but this particular syntax doesn't seem to appear anywhere in the docs. The convention is to just put an `export` in front of the actual type declaration.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nat